# Фильтр значений в датасете R

Tags: регулярные-выражения, r, filter, shiny

Я строю визуализацию в Shiny на основе датасета movies. В датасете в числе прочих для каждого фильма есть атрибут plot_keywords (в формате murder|crime|police).

Необходимо реализовать интерактивный фильтр по этому атрибуту независимо от заглавных/прописных букв - то есть при вводе Murder нужно отобразить все фильмы, где murder присутствует на любом месте атрибута plot_keywords.

В моём коде, если пользователь ничего не вводит в окошке фильтра (по умолчанию), отображаются все фильмы. Какую функцию использовать после else?

Часть кода UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
fluidRow(
 column(3,
        wellPanel(
          textInput("plot", "I want to watch movie about...",NULL)
          )),
```

Часть кода Server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
p <- input$plot
m <- movies %>%
  filter(
    if(p != NULL) && (p != "")
    {plot_keywords == movies$plot_keywords}
    else
    )`
```

Answer (score 0):

А почему не вынести if из фильтра?

```
p <- input$plot
m=movies
if((p != NULL) && (p != "")){
m%>%filter(plot_keywords == movies$plot_keywords)
}
```